# $a-b=\int I(a\leq x)-I(b\leq x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, self-learning

Is it true that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $a-b=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( I(a\leq x)-I(b\leq x)\right)dx$?

I see that the difference of indicator functions is only nonzero when $a\leq x < b$ or $b\leq x <a$. Moreover, $ I(a\leq x)-I(b\leq x)$ equals $1$ in the former case and equals $-1$ in the latter. So, depending whether $a<b$ or not, the above integral is $b-a$ or $a-b$, respectively.

So, is this equality wrong?

*the original statement is for positive real numbers $a,b$, but I believe it does not help much.
**I'm hesitant to conclude it is wrong because this result was used in an article.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an obvious typo. You don't mean integral form $\infty$ to $\infty$, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is always false. If you change the left side to $b-a$ then it is always true.

Comment: Note that if you prove ii for $a<b$ you can get the same identity for $a>b$ by just multiplying both sides by $-1$.

Comment: To see this,  $\int I(a\leq x)-I(b\leq x)=\int_a^b 1 dx$ if $a\leq x <b$ and $\int I(a\leq x)-I(b\leq x)=\int_b^a -1 dx$ if $b\leq x <a$. Then $\int_a^b 1 dx=-\int_b^a -1 dx=b-a$