# Represent the difference of two random variables as indicator functions

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I want to show for any random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have $X-Y = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{1} \{X>a\}- \mathbb{1}\{Y>a\} d a$.

I know that for a postive r.v. $Z$, we have $Z = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}\{ Z>a\} da $. For $X = X^{+} - X^{-}$, we have $X=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{1} \{X>x\}- \mathbb{1}\{-X>x\}d x$.
What can we conclude on $X-Y$?
In general is it correct to say $X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}\{X>x\} dx$?

Comment: I think you meant to say that "For a nonnegative continuous random variable $X$, we have $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X>x\}dx$."

Comment: @Brian Chao. No. I am interested in the random variable rather than its expectation. In particular, $X>a$ stands for $\{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) > a \}$

Comment: Thank you. I have found some discussion here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360374/a-b-int-ia-leq-x-ib-leq-xdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the inequality $X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}\{X>x\} dx$ does not hold, as the integral is divergent ($\mathbb{1}\{X>x\}\to 1$ as $x$ goes to $-\infty$).

In order to prove the wanted equality, let $\omega\in\Omega$, $x=X(\omega)$ and $y=Y(\omega)$. We can assume without loss of generality that $x\geqslant y$. Then
$$
\mathbb{1} \{x>a\}- \mathbb{1}\{y>a\}=\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{ if }a\leqslant y\mbox{ or }a\geqslant x\\
1 &\mbox{ if }y\leqslant a<x.
\end{cases} 
$$